Using VBA, what is a simple and efficient way to remove fragments of a word document?
I have a word document with thousands of options with the pattern in table 1 below.
I want to delete all fragments, including the markers, for all features which the customer omitted in their choice.
How can this  be done using VBA in Microsoft excel?
Table 1. Word Document pattern:
$fragment:[featureName]Heating_mechanism_name$
Productive machine with stainless steel.
$endfragment$

$fragment:[benefitHeader]Heating_mechanism_name$

$endfragment$

$fragment:[benefitBody]Heating_mechanism_name$
This unit is designed for good use. 

This unit comes with a sustainable steel feature.

This unit meets compliance with ISO.
$endfragment$

I tried to loop through paragraphs but sometimes a single feature is spread across multiple paragraphs. Also, I tried wildcards but the ":" and "[" are both special characters in wild card searches.

See https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm
